# How to choose a different mui timepicker variant

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

How can I use “enter time” instead of “select time” using default mui time picker or this one https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/timepicker ?

[mui pickers with variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcdUM.png)

Comment: Could you please share the "Enter Time" variant's link.

Comment: What about KeyboardTimePicker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Web implementation guidance available...

https://material.io/components/time-pickers/web